# Can't update Spring boot to version 2.7.0, maven can't find it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

As topic describes, I can't update Spring boot from version 2.6.6 to 2.7.0. It will not find 2.7.0 and I get stuck with a broken pom.xml and that breaks the project as well.

I have also tried with 2.7.3 without success. Seems like I just can't find any of the 2.7.x versions of spring.

Any advise?

```
Project 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.0' not found
Dependency 'com.h2database:h2:' not found
Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
```

Here's the pom.xml as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>something</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>something else</name>
    <description>some info</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <azure.version>3.13.1</azure.version>
        <azure-identity.version>1.5.0</azure-identity.version>
        <spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets.version>4.0.0</spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets.version>
        <jackson.version>2.12.1</jackson.version>
        <azure-core-serializer-json-jackson.version>1.2.15</azure-core-serializer-json-jackson.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-core-serializer-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-core-serializer-json-jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
            <version>${azure-identity.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-webapp-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaVersion>V2</schemaVersion>
                    <subscriptionId>xxx</subscriptionId>
                    <resourceGroup>xxxx</resourceGroup>
                    <appName>xxx</appName>
                    <pricingTier>P1v2</pricingTier>
                    <region>West Europe</region>
                    <runtime>
                        <os>linux</os>
                        <javaVersion>java 11</javaVersion>
                        <webContainer>Java SE</webContainer>
                    </runtime>
                    <!-- start of APP_SETTINGS -->
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>JAVA_OPTS</name>
                            <value>-Dserver.port=80</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                    <!-- end of APP_SETTINGS -->
                    <deployment>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>*.jar</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </deployment>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Is there any issue with the pom.xml?

Comment: please share your pom.xml file. Did you specify the version of the library?

Comment: Hi @David I added the pom to the post.

Comment: please try specifying the version of the not found libraries. Also try ``mvn -U clean install``

Comment: I had a coworker update to 2.7.0 without any issue and after I deleted my m2 folder and pulled changes, I could rebuild! I will keep in mind to check versions and add them. But should/would not Spring resolve the versions for the plugin for me?

Comment: If your local artifact repository got corrupted somehow, you can see broken dependency resolution. Adding `-U` as David suggested, or removing the repo and starting fresh as you did, is a great first step to troubleshooting. Especially if it works properly for a teammate.

Comment: Ok, I will google the -U addition, thanks for your support @David and user944849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a coworker update to 2.7.0 without any issue and after I deleted my m2 folder and pulled changes, I could rebuild! I will keep in mind to check versions and add them.

As @David mvn -U clean install, I checked it out:
-U,--update-snapshots
Forces a check for updated releases and snapshots on remote repositories
Probably will try this next time since my coworker had already updated before I read the comment. Thanks!